# Router for quering MySQL results in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

What should I consider in order to refactor the following code ?

It seems very close to proudly become a Pyramid of Doom:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {

    getId = req.params.id
    obj = {}

    db.con.query('SELECT * FROM employees where id=?', getId, function(err, results) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('error in query')
            return

        } else {
            try {
                obj = {
                    id: results[0].id,
                    name: results[0].name,
                    location: results[0].location
                }
                res.render('showuser')

            } catch (err) {
                res.status(500)
                res.render('error', { error: err, id: getId })
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Really doesn't look that bad, regardless consider using `async` / `await` for more succinct code. Presumably the DB lib you're using supports Promises.

Answer (score 1):

Are we actually using the `obj` variable? It seems like you are not using it unless you were intending to pass to the `render` function. I don't think the try block is necessary. You can first check if `results` contains elements in it, so doing `results[0].X` will not return you an error since `results[0]` will never be `undefined`.

Here's an improved version:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  const getId = req.params.id;

  db.con.query('SELECT * FROM employees where id = ?', getId, function(err, results) {
    if (err || !results.length) {
      console.log('error in query');
      res.status(500).render('error', { error: err, id: getId });
      return;
    }

    var obj = {
      id: results[0].id,
      name: results[0].name,
      location: results[0].location
    };
    res.render('showuser', obj); // Assuming you're using obj to render
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {

    const getId = req.params.id

    db.con.query('SELECT * FROM employees where id=?', getId, function(err, results) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('error in query')
            return

        }

        try {
            const obj = {
                id: results[0].id,
                name: results[0].name,
                location: results[0].location
            }
            res.render('showuser')

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500)
            res.render('error', { error: err, id: getId })
        }
    })
});
```

There are a few of things I changed

- added `const` to `getId` now it may not interfere with other variables called `getId` in your module
- moved definition of the `obj` inside the `try` block, since this is the only place you are using it as well as added `const` for the same reason
- since you have `return` in your `if (err)` condition, the function will end there if it errors. Therefore, `else` is unnecessary here and was removed